# Picking shortest height of divs

Tags: javascript, html, select, shortest

I have, in the past, used this script to set all the divs of the same class to the height of the tallest div.

```
equalheight = function(container){
    var currentTallest = 0,
         currentRowStart = 0,
         rowDivs = new Array(),
         $el,
         topPosition = 0;
     $(container).each(function() {

       $el = $(this);
       $($el).height('auto')
       topPostion = $el.position().top;

       if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
         for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
           rowDivs[currentDiv].attr("style", "height: " + currentTallest + "px !important;");
         }
         rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
         currentRowStart = topPostion;
         currentTallest = $el.height();
         rowDivs.push($el);
       } else {
         rowDivs.push($el);
         currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
      }
       for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
         rowDivs[currentDiv].attr("style", "height: " + currentTallest + "px !important;");
       }
     });
    }
$(document).ready(function() {  
    equalheight('.divs_to_match');              
});
```

This time, however, I am trying to select the SHORTEST div and then set the max-height of the others to match so that the divs are cropped to the same height. Can someone please help me modify this to make that happen?

Edit - Here is a jsfiddle showing how it currently works - https://jsfiddle.net/mortalwombat7/h61oc67x/11/

Comment: I figured it out. I just changed this line to show greater-than instead of less-than. I tried it before and had an issue. I must have had a typo or something: 

currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that worked:

```
equalheight = function(container){

var currentTallest = 0,
     currentRowStart = 0,
     rowDivs = new Array(),
     $el,
     topPosition = 0;
 $(container).each(function() {

   $el = $(this);
   $($el).height('auto')
   topPostion = $el.position().top;

   if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
     for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
       rowDivs[currentDiv].attr("style", "max-height: " + currentTallest + "px !important; overflow: hidden;");
     }
     rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
     currentRowStart = topPostion;
     currentTallest = $el.height();
     rowDivs.push($el);
   } else {
     rowDivs.push($el);
     currentTallest = (currentTallest > $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
  }
   for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
     rowDivs[currentDiv].attr("style", "max-height: " + currentTallest + "px !important; overflow: hidden;");
   }
 });
}

$(window).ready(function() {
  equalheight('.main article');
});


$(window).resize(function(){
  equalheight('.main article');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//min and max functions -- from MDN
function minHeight(arr) {
    return Math.min.apply(null, arr);
}

//in case you want max at a later date
function maxHeight(arr) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
}

var equalHeights = function(elements){
    var tracker = [],
    min = 0;
    //max = 0; -- you'd replace min with max if you want the opposite

    elements.each(function(){
        tracker.push(Math.floor($(this).height()));
    });

    min = minHeight(tracker);
    max = maxHeight(tracker);
    elements.each(function(){
        $(this).height(min);
    });
};

var min = equalHeights($('.main article'));
```